# PHP: -IF- Preguntar si el campo posee letras

Tags: php

Buenas a todos!

Me topé con algo que me está haciendo renegar y aún no encuentro la solución:

A mi código ingresa un campo el cual si posee LETRAS lo anulo.

Es decir:

```
                        $valor= "1A8CF4D2414E000094136783";
                        #FILTRADO CAMPO 1


                        if( preg_match('/^[A-Z]+$/', $valor) )
                        { 

                            echo('Lectura posee letras.');
                            $valor = "0";

                        } else {
                            echo('Lectura NO posee letras.');
                        }
```

El problema es que siempre me devuelve el valor de else aunque sea verdedera la condición. Qué puede estar mal?

Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que preg_match devuelve un entero, no un booleano.

> preg_match() devuelve 1 si pattern coincide con el subject dado, 0 si
>   no, o FALSE si ocurrió un error.
>
> **Advertencia** Esta función puede devolver el valor booleano FALSE, pero
>   también puede devolver un valor no booleano que se evalúa como FALSE.

Todo lo siguiente, se considera falso, y por lo tanto cae por el else:

> el integer 0 (cero)
>   el float 0.0 (cero)
>   el valor string vacío, y el string "0"
>   un array con cero elementos

En tu caso, estas preguntando si la cadena solo contiene letras, cosa que es falso. entonces devuelve 0, que es falso. Debes comprobar la regex, una que te podria funcionar seria:

```
[A-Z]+
```

Comment: Buena puntuación lo de la advertencia

Comment: No entiendo la primera parte de la respuesta. Tal cual estás diciendo `0` es un valor que se evalúa como falso, por lo tanto `if (preg_match( $re, $valor)) {` está perfecto... Sólo la corrección del regex para que no use `^` ni `$` es lo que aplica en este caso... Y un detalle, no hace falta coincidir con múltiples letras, sobra con la primera: `if (preg_match('/[a-záéíóúüñ]/iu', $valor)) {` ... O, si se prefiere `/[^\W_\d]/u`

Comment: Le explique porque siempre cai por el else @Mariano. Luego de eso puse una cadena que podia llegar a resolver su problema. pero no me centre en la regex, ya que vi que no estaba entendiendo el problema del if.

Comment: dijo que siempre salia por el else.. no me centre en la regex.. me centre en que podia tener una confunción de como funcionaba la funcion preg_match...

Answer (score 2):

```
$valor= "1A8CF4D2414E000094136783";

if ( preg_match('/[A-Z]/i', $valor) )
{
    echo('Lectura posee letras.');
} else {
    echo('Lectura NO posee letras.');
}
```

El `/i` evita la distinción de mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: avisa si te sirve ;)

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 2):

Por aquí hay gente con muuucha mas experiencia que yo en Regex. Pero voy a intentar responderte.

Estás preguntando si coincide con:

```
/^    Empieza por
[A-Z] Un rango de A a Z
+     Una o más coincidencias
$/    Termina por
```

Por lo que solo te está admitiendo cadenas del tipo *KJBFKGJBKSBGBJKVJV*.

Si eliminas los delimitadores `^` y `$` va a buscar cualquier coincidencia sin tener en cuenta expresamente que debe iniciar o acabar con los caracteres indicados. Lo cual resolvería el problema.

```
$valor="1A8CF4D2414E000094136783";
#FILTRADO CAMPO 1

if(preg_match('/[A-Za-z]+/', $valor)) {
    echo 'Lectura posee letras.';
    $valor="0";
}
else {
    echo 'Lectura NO posee letras.';
}
```

Comment: O prueba con ver si es numérico. `preg_match('/^[0-9]/i', $valor)`

Comment: @Gustavo claro, yo lo haría así por lógica, si solo admites números, cualquier cosa distinta de un entero es suficiente. _is\_int($valor)_. Lo he puesto en base a su misma estructura.

Comment: no @Gustavo, como OP no aclaro el formato de la cadena que viene, esa Regexp falla para cosas que no empiecen con un numero. y /i no sirve con numeros!

Comment: @OscarR esa fue mi primera idea, pero si son todos numeros y muy largo, va a dar overflow.. entonces tampoco sirve...

Comment: @gbianchi ¿en que escenario se produce eso? no me ha pasado, es por curiosidad.

Comment: @OscarR tienes razon, se me mezclo con otro lenguaje. no te da overflow, pero te va a dar falso, porque Comprueba si el tipo de variable dado es integer.y en este caso.. es un string. Tampoco puedes usar is numeric, porque una e dentro de la cadena se considera un numero.

Comment: @gbianchi  interesante, lo de la _e_ lo apunto y lo pruebo, no conocía ese comportamiento. Gracias por el dato!!

Comment: Me sirvió mucho esta info! Desconocía totalmente  Reged. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

intenta esta solucion

```
$valor= "1A8CF4D2414E000094136783";
                    #FILTRADO CAMPO 1

if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $valor) )
{ 

 echo('Lectura posee letras.');
 $valor = "0";

 } else {
     echo('Lectura NO posee letras.');
 }
```

Comment: Deberías explicar la motivación de la respuesta... qué está mal y por qué tu código soluciona el problema.